# Timeout with ActiveRecord（ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError ）

Tags: ruby, activerecord, connection, timeout, sinatra

While creating an application using ActiveRecord with sinatra, I encountered such an error.

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError at / could not obtain a database
>   connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.005 seconds)

What I was about to do was to "get a profile image from Twitter API, save it in a database, and embed it in index.erb". I stopped here.

The code is below.

main.rb

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/reloader"
require "twitter"
require "active_record"


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: "sqlite3",
    database: "./image.db"
)   

class Src < ActiveRecord::Base
end

def get_profile_image
    @srcs = Src.order("id desc").all
end

def add_profile_image(twitter_id)

    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(
        consumer_key: "[CONSUMER_KEY]",
        consumer_secret: "[CONSUMER_SECRET]",
        access_token: "[ACCESS_TOMEN]",
        access_token_secret: "[ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET]"
    )
    user = client.user(twitter_id)
    url = user.profile_image_url

    src = Src.new(account: twitter_id, url: url)
    src.save 
end

def delete_img(twitter_id)
    Src.find_by(account: twitter_id).delete
end



get "/" do
    get_profile_image
    erb :index
end

post "/" do
    add_profile_image(params[:id])
    get_profile_image
    erb :index
end

get "/delete" do
    delete_img(params[:id])
    get_profile_image
    erb :index
end
```

index.erb

```
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value="enter">
  </form>

  <form method="get" action="/delete">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value="delete">
  </form>

  <% @srcs.each do |src| %>
    <div id="images-space" style="float: left;" class="imgs">
      <img data-id="<%= src.id %>" src="<%= src.url %>">
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

DB table name is "srcs" and column is

- id integer primary key
- account text
- url text

This kind of error is the first time for me, but where is the problem?

Comment: Please use plain English on that site.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it understandable to all SO users - in English.

Comment: I'm sorry.I have fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple the connection to your database from your code in a separate script to test and publish that with the error produced so that we can reproduce the problem, something like

```
require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: "sqlite3",
    database: "./image.db"
) 

if !ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('SRCS')
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table 'SRCS' do |table|
      table.column :account, :string
      table.column :url, :string
    end
  end
end

class Src < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name  = 'SRCS'
end

p Src.first
```